# Hide parameter from Advanced Find

Tags: parameters, reporting, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way to hide a report parameter from the CRM advanced find interface?  I have an expression based parameter that does not need to be selected by the user, however when I upload the report, CRM detects the prefiltering parameter and adds a prompt for it in the prefiltering interface.

Comment: So I have worked around this problem by using a subreport and restructuring my main report to only use one prefilter parameter and pass the remaining computed parameters into a subreport which uses them directly.

Answer (score 2):

In the Customisation area, go to properties for that field and change the "Searchable?" paramater to "No". This will hide it from your Advanced Find field lists.

Incidentally this is very useful for hiding fields from advanced finds that you also hide on the form, such as "Category" fields on activities if users don't use them.

Comment: I guess I should have specified, what I am working on is not an Entity, it's an SSRS report.  Sorry I totally forgot you can do advanced find directly on Entities themselves (head has been stuck in reporting that long).  So what I have is a dataset in my SSRS report with a prefilter.  The prefilter is a dataset parameter which is computed using custom code within the report.  So I don't want that parameter appearing as a prompt to the user when I run the report in CRM, however I cannot find any way of hiding it from CRM.